# Encode associative array as valid php

Tags: php, encode

Is there a way to encode variables as strings that can be evaluated as php code? In particular, I'm interested in associative arrays. (Scalar values and indexed arrays are encoded as valid php code by `json_encode`. I don't need to encode objects and resources).

```
$Array = ['1', 2, 'key' => 'value'];
php_encode($Array); // => "[0 => '1', 1 => 2, 'key' => 'value']" or similar
```

Comment: I am not sure what are you talkng about..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `var_export` with the second parameter set to true:

```
function php_encode($val)
{
    return var_export($val, true);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php